# vue-cookies not able to set sameSite and secure attributes

Tags: vue.js, webpack, cookies, vue-cli, vue-cookies

I am using vue-cookies for my vue.js project. I am setting the cookie from

```
this.$cookies.set('session',response.data.sessionCookie,'7d',null,null,true,'None')
```

and its not being set when i see the cookies but when i am using

```
 this.$cookies.set('session',response.data.sessionCookie)
```

I am seeing the cookies being set.
What should I do? attaching the screenshots of cookies being set and my sample code.
I am using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies

[Check highlighted text where I am setting the cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9n4p.png)

Using second code where the didn't used any attributes, my cookie is being set and i can see it in the cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely happening because you are attempting to set a secure cookie in the dev environment under `http://`, which is insecure.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#Secure) on secure cookies:

> Note that insecure sites (http:) can't set cookies with the Secure directive.

You can try to test this on a secure server or run Vue CLI in [secure mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps).  To do that, add the following to *vue.config.js* in your project root:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    https: true
  }
}
```

Make sure you type `https://localhost:8080/` in the browser after restarting the dev server with these settings, it will not redirect if you type `http://`.

Comment: doesn't work for me: ```failed to load config from vite.config.js
11:27:01 AM [vite] Build failed with 1 error:
vite.config.js:7:2: ERROR: Expected "}" but found "module"```

Comment: @Xb74Dkjb - That's because you're using Vite.  This question is about VueCLI, which uses Webpack, which the config in this answer is for.